# How to decide when the method should be called

Tags: c++, methods

I have a numerous amount of methods to validate a certain part of a string and they are all in the main method.

i.e if certain part of a string = .E/ call the E method

but i think it would be better to not have all the methods waiting in the main method to be called. example string

i.e there is a method called validateD which will not execute because .D/ is not present in the strng however it is in the main method how can i move it from the main method but still call it if a .D/34455 string occured. Is this possible

```
int main()
{
    //EXAMPE STRING string str
  .F/12345
    .I/323244
    .O/243434


    //METHODS
    elementF f;
    f.retrieveMaskF();
    out.push_back(f.validateF(str));

     elementI i;
        i.retrieveMaskI();
        out.push_back(i.validateI(str));

    elementO o;
    o.retrieveMaskO();
    out.push_back(o.validateO(str));


        elementD d;
       d.retrieveMaskD();
      out.push_back(d.validateD(str));
}
```

Comment: Is it the case that only one of the functions will be called for any given string?

Comment: no its in the case so the code is intelligent enough to know when to be called instead of waiting  there in the main method @hmjd